# How to update php version from 8.1.17 to 8.1.25 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, php-8

on a CentOS7 server
running PHP 8.1.17

and I just to to do a simple update to v. 8.1.25

I have done:

## updated packages

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum upgrade
```

## Installed Epel

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

## Installed Remi

```
sudo yum -y install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
```

But none of that is bringing PHP latest 8.1 version (which currently is 8.1.25)

What do you think I'm missing???

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a coding / programming question. (Why not post it on ServerFault ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning**: CentOS 7 is close to its end of life in a few months, so I recommend a more recent version, EL-8 or EL-9, especially for modern features such as PHP 8.x

For a proper repository configuration and usage, you have to follow the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

At least, you need to enable the **remi-php81** repository

Comment: Right on the dot. 
I've missed to enable the remi-php81 repository
Thanks!